# Manage MS Powerpoint slides

Tags: gratis, document-management, slideshow, powerpoint

I am looking for a software to manage my Microsoft Powerpoint slides.
Over the years I have produced very many powerpoint presentations. While doing that I reused countless slides (as they were or with slight modifications) while producing new ones all the time.
Now I have this huge amount of presentations, partly overlapping and redundant.

What I am looking for is a software to manage all my slides and ideally with the ability to manage different versions of one slide.

There are commercial ones like [slidebank](http://www.slidebank.com/) or [Shufflrr](http://www.shufflrr.com/) but I need it to be free (or at least affordable for students).

It would also be great if it was not a cloud/online solution.

A great bonus would be the ability to use it in groups to also have access to slides of other members of the group.

Comment: Shufflrr and Slidebank are paid monthly and seem to be available for 5+ user only. How much money are you willing to spend for a perpetual one user license? I'm uncertain what price is acceptable for a student. It may vary across countries.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Zoom](http://www.simplyzoom.com/).

So far

- it reliably imported my 1200 slides
- it works offline. I checked that by denying Internet access via the Windows Firewall.
- it's a [$89 one time price](http://www.simplyzoom.com/download/), which might be affordable for students
- I could easily merge slides of different presentations to a new presentation

Since it works offline, I doubt it can share slides for a group of people. Maybe you can use Dropbox to simply share the slides and everyone can then use Zoom on the Dropbox folder.

I don't think it can manage different versions of slides inside a presentation (like a backup functionality).